# multiple SUMPRODUCT * by a value and added all together

Tags: excel

Can anyone help me? I'm having problems creating a sumproduct for multiple criteria.
I want to sum occurrences of a string 'X' in a range 'B1:M1' and then multiply this by the value in cell 'A1'

I want to do the same for the next line i.e. sum occurrences of code 'X' in a range 'B2:M2' and then multiply this by the value in cell 'B1'

I want to repeat this process for the next 50 lines...

Finally, I want to add all of these values together.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
=sumproduct(($B2:$M2="x")*index($1:$1, 1, row(1:1)))
```

Fill down for B3:M3=x*B1, B4:M4=x*C1, etc

Comment: Is there a way of putting all of this together into one formula? I don't need the results for separate lines but the one total result.